# Right aligning a single item in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

In my `React Native` app, I have a card with a bunch of buttons at the bottom of it -- see image below.

[image]

I want to leave the first two icons where they are, on the left but move the (X) button all the way to the right. How do I accomplish this?

Here's what I have right now which is not working:

```
<Card style={styles.listItem}>
   <Card.Content>
      <Paragraph>{item.description}</Paragraph>
   </Card.Content>
   <Card.Actions>
      <Button><Icon name="checkcircleo" /> </Button> 
      <Button><Icon name="clockcircleo" /> </Button>
      <Button style={{ alignItems: 'stretch' }}><Icon name="closecircle" /> </Button>
   </Card.Actions>
</Card>
```

Comment: You could group the two buttons and use `justifyContent: 'space-between'` on your `Card.Actions`

Answer (score 10):

To align the last button to the right, add `{ marginLeft: 'auto' }` style to it.

To align all buttons to the right, add `{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }` style to `Card.Actions`.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This should be accepted as best answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `alignSelf: "flex-end"` to the button style:

```js
<Card style={styles.listItem}>
    <Card.Content>
        <Paragraph>{item.description}</Paragraph>
    </Card.Content>

    <Card.Actions>
        <Button>
            <Icon name="checkcircleo" />
        </Button> 

        <Button>
            <Icon name="clockcircleo" />
        </Button>

        <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
            <Icon name="closecircle" />
        </Button>
    </Card.Actions>
</Card>
```

Comment: Didn't work but I'm wondering if that's because I use `react-native-paper`.

Comment: No, you may simply need to add `flex: 1` to `<Card.Actions>`

Comment: Didn't work. Icons are still sitting next to each other. `<Card.Actions style={{ flex: 1 }}>` and the third button is exactly like in your code above with `alignSelf: 'flex-end'`

Answer (score 0):

You can group the first two buttons by flex and `flex direction:'row'` and you can use the `justifyContent:space-between` on the group button and the cross button.

Here is an example of how it can be achieved. :

```
<Card.Actions>
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}} >
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <Button>
            <Icon name="checkcircleo" />
        </Button> 

        <Button>
            <Icon name="clockcircleo" />
        </Button>
      </View>
<View>
        <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
            <Icon name="closecircle" />
        </Button>
</View>
</View>
    </Card.Actions>
```

Here is the example of the expo snack : [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/PN7co1jPd)

Do check out.

Feel free for doubts

Comment: This didn't work for me. I wonder if it's because I'm using `react-native-paper` and my `Card` is actually imported from `react-native-paper` and not the standard one in `React Native`.